# How to kill background Activity in Android studio

Tags: android, background

I have the MainActivity and the secon_Activity in Android Studio, from MainActivity I go to second_Activity using Intent, then in the second_Activity I want to finish that activity, I do it but the first activity remains in  background, how can I do to end or kill both activities.

Here the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button send_button;
EditText send_text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_activity);

    send_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button_id);
    send_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.send_text_id);

    send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String str = send_text.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("message_key", str);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here de second_Activity:

```
public class Second_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView receiver_msg;
Button finish_button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_activity);

    receiver_msg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.received_value_id);
    finish_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish_button_id);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("message_key");
    receiver_msg.setText(str);

    finish_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Please describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a Kiosk app and from my searching you can't remove it from the "recent" apps.
You can how ever, use ActivityManager as follows:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) Context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.moveTaskToFront(myAppId, 0);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(Activity_A_Package_Name);
```

Requires:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

It should kill it, usually.

Comment: Not, the MainActivity is still there

Comment: @w1ll there being where? in the recent apps? I said, I haven't found a way to remove if from "recent apps" but this will usually kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `System.exit(1)` instead of `finish()`